# call part of stream once with multiple subscribers?

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have custom Rx Adapter for socket communication.
Outside of it I observe Flowable with messages.
Then I have some manager that handles every message and then emit it further.

```
       fun observeSocket() = socketManager
                .observe()
                .doOnNext{
                    insideMessageHandler.handle(it)
                }
```

Then I have two subscribers that does observeSocket().subscribe()

The problem is that with every message insideMessageHandler.handle(it) is called twice. I want to find the way where part of stream will be common for every subscriber. Unfortunately .share() operator at the end of observeSocket() don't work.

I have something like this twice:

```
         /onNextInside
Flowable/-onNextOutsideSubscriber1
Flowable\-onNextOutsideSubscriber2
         \-onNextInside
```

And I want to have something like this:

```
         /-onNextInside
Flowable/-onNextOutsideSubscriber1
        \-onNextOutsideSubscriber2
```

In code it looks like

```
insideManager.observeSocket().subscribe({do something first})
insideManager.observeSocket().subscribe({do something second})
```

The problem is that in this case I have onNextInside called twice

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the re-creation of the observable:

```
fun observeSocket() = socketManager
        .observe()
        .doOnNext{
            insideMessageHandler.handle(it)
        }
```

With every call to `observeSocket()` you create a new chain, so putting the `share()` there wouldn't make a difference.

Instead define this chain as a shared singleton:

```
private val _observeSocket = socketManager
        .observe()
        .doOnNext{
            insideMessageHandler.handle(it)
        }
        .share()


fun observeSocket() = _observeSocket
```

Comment: Like the answer ;-)

Comment: Great it works almost perfectly! Changed orders of the operator and now it is exact what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For this case you have Subjects.

```
var yourSubject = PublishSubject<Type>.create()
fun observeSocket() = socketManager.doOnNext(yourSubject::onNext)
```

Then you can observe on your observeSocket() and another/multiple subscriber on the subject.

If you want to share the emitting of one Observables you can use the share() operator which makes sure that even when multiple subscribers are subscribed it only create one instance and share the emitted data using

```
fun observeSocket() = socketManager
            .doOnNext(insideMessageHandler::handle)
            .share()
```

Anyway, it's not a good usecase for reactive stuff to flat/emit to another observables in doOnNext for this purpose.

Better share one Flowable and subscribe multiple times and flatmap the values to your need instead of putting everything in one flowable since if there's an error in the stream the whole stream may not emit any more data.

Comment: doOnNext don't emit anything 
it's just doing something with the object, for example Log it 
I will fix my drawing :)

Comment: Ok, hold on. Ill check in a few minutes. Can you provide sample data because its not really clear what your asking for